# Java search-Arraylist

Tags: java

```
ArrayList searchList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList words=(ArrayList) request.getSession().getAttribute("words");
words.add("one");
words.add("twenty one");
words.add("thirty one");
words.add("two");
words.add("twenty two");
words.add("thirty two");
words.add("three");
words.add("twenty three");
words.add("thirty three");'
```

If I have this arraylist and I want to search all the strings containing one(i.e. one,twenty one and thirty one), what logic should I use? Means how should I do that?

Comment: please let me know ow can we do that...

Answer (score 3):

```
for (String item : searchList) {
    if (item.contains("one") {
        // Do something. Like adding the result to a different list.
        // If you need the index from the original list, you a for instead of a for each
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//iterate through words
for(String str : list){
  //check if word contains the key
  if(str.contains(key)){ 
     //add its reference to another resultant list
     result.add(str);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String word : words) {
   if (word.contains("one")) {
       //we have a match
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to loop thru the elements. Look for ways to loop thru an ArrayList: that can be indexed or with the

```
for (x : collect)
```

notation.

In the loop you have to do some pattern matching. Read String Java API doc for a method.

(Give'em some think food ...)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using iterators if the condition will be more complex

```
    public interface IPredicate<T> {

        boolean check(T t);

    }


public class PredicatIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {

        private final Iterator<T> iterator;
        private final IPredicate<T> predicate;

        public PredicatIterable(Iterable<T> iterable, IPredicate<T> predicate) {
            this.iterator = iterable.iterator();
            this.predicate = predicate;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<T>() {

                T current;

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {

                    if(iterator.hasNext()) {
                        T next = iterator.next();

                        if(predicate.check(next)) {
                            current = next;
                            return true;
                        } 
                        current = null;
                    }

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public T next() {
                    return current;
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid useage of method");
                }



            };
        }

    }
```

To validate more the single predicate you can create also method that is responsible for conuntion or alternative of two IPredicate argument.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when searching an item in a `List`, the best solution is to sort your `List` first using `Collections.sort()` method. Then using the `Collections.binarySearch()` method, find your element.
In this case your elements are `String` type that are `Comparable` and can be sorted alphabetically otherwise you needed to implement `Comparable` interface for your element class type.